# What's the logic behind such gradient descent

Tags: gradient-descent

The gradient descent is motivated from the leetcode question of minimal distance:

https://leetcode.com/problems/best-position-for-a-service-centre/

$$\arg\min\limits_{x_c,y_c}\sum\limits_i\sqrt{(x_i-x_c)^2+(y_i-y_c)^2}.$$

And here is one of the correct solution (`dist` is distance function):

```
double getMinDistSum(vector<vector<int>>& positions) {
    constexpr double kDelta = 1e-6;
    int n = positions.size();
    vector<double> center(2, 0.0);
    for (const auto& pos : positions)
    {
        center[0] += pos[0];
        center[1] += pos[1];
    }
    center[0] = center[0] / n;
    center[1] = center[1] / n;
    double minDist = dist(center, positions);

    double step = 1.0;
    while (step > kDelta)
    {
        bool reduceStep = true;
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
            {
                if (abs(y) + abs(x) != 1)
                    continue;

                double curX = center[0] + x * step;
                double curY = center[1] + y * step;
                double newDist = dist({ curX, curY }, positions);
                if (newDist < minDist)
                {
                    minDist = newDist;
                    reduceStep = false;
                    center[0] = curX;
                    center[1] = curY;
                }
            }
        if (reduceStep)
        {
            step /= 10.0;
        }
    }
    return minDist;
}
```

The logic is that

1. each time only move in the decreasing of the five directions:$(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ and $(0,0).$
2. If none of them decrease, the step reduces the ten times

I cannot understand why such gradient descent works?

Comment: @Dave I closed Cross Validated one.

Comment: I believe the loops actually check nine directions, including e.g. (1,0).

Comment: @BenReiniger I think `if (abs(y) + abs(x) != 1)` this condition is definitely added manually for some purposes.

Comment: ah, should've kept reading past the loop intros, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not gradient descent, but instead it is [coordinate descent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent).

The logic is the same as walking up a hill in order to reach the summit.

You do not have to be aware of the entire hill and the area around you is sufficient. As long as you always take a step to a higher point then you will be able to get to the top.

There are problems however. The function needs to be convex and smooth, otherwise you can get stuck in a local point that is not the peak.

Comment: why does he choose such five directions but not simply left, right, up and down?

Comment: @user6703592 left,right,up,down are just labels of those directions. E.g. if you imagine a Cartesian plane with an x-axis and y-axis and you are facing along the positive direction of the y-axis then Up = (0,+1), Down = (0,-1), Right = (+1,0) and Left = (-1,0).

Comment: yes, I mean why not choose (0,1), (1,0), (-1,0), (0,-1) those four directions

Comment: @user6703592 I made a little error with interpreting $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ you do not align along up along the y-axis but along the diagonal and you could still add labels Up = (+1,+1), Down = (-1,-1), Right = (+1,-1), Left = (-1,+1). Sidenote: in the code it is the directions (0,+1),  (0,-1), (+1,0) and (-1,0) and not (+1,+1), (-1,-1), (+1,-1), (-1,+1). There is a loop with all, nine directions (including 0,0) and the diagonal directions are excluded with `if (abs(y) + abs(x) != 1)`